# What happens with Microsoft Graph webhooks if the receiver is down?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

[The documentation](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/webhooks) for Microsoft Graph webhooks is not clear on the durability of events. If a client creates a subscription and then subsequently goes down (say, for maintenance), what happens to events that occur while the client is unavailable? Are they queued and retried by the Microsoft Graph until the client comes back online, or are they lost? If they are queued, for how long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph Webhook will try to send the events a number of times **within 4 hours** window. If the client does not come back online **after 4 hours**, then these events will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks, is this officially documented anywhere? Is the period likely to change?

Comment: It's not super-likely to change, but we don't feel confident enough in that statement to make it part of the breaking change contract just yet.